# Can branched curve be applied as curve modifier?

Tags: curve-modifier

I am trying to make a branching road like this: [image]

I created same curve by manually drawing it, and a road sample. Applied to road that curve as a curve modifier, but, unfortunately at the branch point, the road does not branching as well.

[image]

Is it possible to do it that way? Blender 2.93.4

Comment: nope, you can't. Read this for more info: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40343/branching-bezier-curves

Comment: @Chris, yeah, already read that

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions/57288#57288